# Where to find authors of the articles from the Times archive?

Tags: academic-writing, research, journalism

I'm currently writing a paper on the historical background of the Bond movies. I've found a very interesting piece of information that is only mentioned on Wikipedia.

Here are the bibliography details:
"Money-Making Films of 1962". The Times (London). 4 January 1964. p. 4.

Since this site cannot be used as a reliable source, I tried to find the article in the Times archive. Even there I couldn't find any information about the author of the original article.
Then, I tried other online archives and libraries but also with no results. 
I want to find this article and analyse it, really bad.

Could anybody, please, help me find the author or direct me to some magical web-page where I could check such information?

Comment: Unfortunately the actual article appears to be behind a paywall, so its difficult to actually go and have a look! - However if there is no obvious sign of who has written it, maybe an email to the times could be the magic you're looking for...

Comment: I agree. That seems to be the last, and only possible, solution. Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 1):

What a shame. I have access to the Times Digital Archive and would gladly have sent @charlie48 a copy of that article, but he or she hasn't been here since June 2015 and that paper of theirs has probably long been written, submitted to their professor, marked, and forgotten.

For future persons facing a similar problem:

The Times Digital Archive and most other online archives of large national newspapers are usually accessible through any university library and many larger public libraries, and most university libraries offer guest access to their research tools for visitors. Universities and colleges are never far in any Western country, so just go there and ask.

---

This specific article was published anonymously in the Times. The style guide you employ will explain how to correctly cite anonymous sources. The Times Digital Archive itself proposes the following citation:

> "Money-Making Films Of 1962." Times [London, England] 4 Jan. 1963: 4. The Times Digital Archive. Web. 21 Mar. 2018.

The date at the end is the date when I accessed the archive.